# NoMethodError in Rooms#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am getting NoMethodError in Rooms#index, specifically undefined method `boolean_array_from_amenities_integer' for #.  I defined "boolean_array_from_amenities_integer" in the Room.rb model however I am not picking it up.  Any help would be appreciated.

**room.rb**

```
class Room < ActiveRecord::Base

    validates :amenities, presence: true

    def self.amenities_list
    ["Smoking Allowed",
     "Pets Allowed",
     "TV",
     "Cable TV",
     "Internet",
     "Wireless Internet",
     "Air Conditioning",
     "Heating",
     "Elevator in Building",
     "Handicap Accessible",
     "Pool",
     "Kitchen",
     "Free parking on premise",
     "Doorman",
     "Gym",
     "Hot Tub",
     "Indoor Fireplace",
     "Buzzer/Wireless Intercom",
     "Breakfast",
     "Family/Kid Friendly",
     "Suitable for Events",
     "Washer",
     "Dryer"]
  end

 def boolean_array_from_amenities_integer
    [].tap do |amenities_list|
    Room.amenities_list.length do |order|
      amenities_list << (self.amenities & 2 ** order > 0)
        end
        end
      end

  end
```

**rooms_conroller.rb**

```
class RoomsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :require_current_user!, only: [:new, :create]

  def index
    @room = Room.all
   end

  def show
    @room = Room.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @room = Room.new
  end

  def create
    @room = Room.new(params[:room])

    @room.set_amenities_from_options_list!(params[:room_amenities_indicies])
    if @room.save

    redirect_to @room
     else
    flash.now[:errors] = @room.errors if @room.errors
     render :new
    end
  end
```

private

def room_params
    params.require(:room).permit(:amenities, :amenities_indices)
  end
end

**new.html.erb**

```
 <label for="room-amenities" class="top">Amenities</label>
    <ul class="group" id="room-amenities">
      <% Room.amenities_list.each_with_index do |amenity, index| %>
        <li class="checkbox-li">
          <input type="checkbox" name="room_amenities_indicies[]" value="<%= index %>">
            <%= amenity %>
          </input>
        </li>
      <% end %>
    </ul><br>

  <input type="submit" class="button blue input-large label-offset-button" value="Create room">
</form>
```

**index.html.erb**

```
    <label for="amenities-tab-button">Amenities</label>
      <div class="tab-content group">
          <% amenities_list = Room.amenities_list %>
  <ul>

    <% @room.boolean_array_from_amenities_integer.each_with_index do |amenity_available,index| %>
      <% if amenity_available %>
        <li class="available-amenity">
      <% else %>
        <li class="unavailable-amenity">
      <% end %>
          <%= amenities_list[index] %>
        </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>

    </div>
```

Comment: can you post the entire stack trace of the error?

Answer (score 0):

there is a syntax error in controller

you forgot to close the index method with "end"

```
  def index
    @room = Room.all
  end

  def show
    @room = Room.find(params[:id])
  end
```

Edited

in Index view you use @room variable which is array calculated from index action, you need to get the instance of room model.

@room = Room.all

Comment: sorry i did put an end in but did not put that up there, that's not it

Comment: Edited the answer.

 in Index view you use @room variable which is array and calculated from index action, you are expecting it be instance of room model.

Answer (score 0):

It is often good to follow naming (and other) conventions.

What you have in your view is an attempt to retrieve an the boolean_array from an *array of room instances*, when your intention is to retrieve it from *each instance*.

In the controller:

```
def index
  @rooms = Room.all   # <=== use the plural
end
```

And in the index view:

```
<% @rooms.each do |room| %>
  ...
  <% room.boolean_array_from_amenities_integer.each_with_index do |amenity_available,index| %>  
    ...
  <% end %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: i got undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Are you using @room**s**.each?

Answer (score 0):

You should make `amenities_list` a constant on the model:

```
AMENITIES_LIST = ["Smoking Allowed",
     "Pets Allowed",
     "TV",
     "Cable TV",
     "Internet",
     "Wireless Internet",
     "Air Conditioning",
     "Heating",
     "Elevator in Building",
     "Handicap Accessible",
     "Pool",
     "Kitchen",
     "Free parking on premise",
     "Doorman",
     "Gym",
     "Hot Tub",
     "Indoor Fireplace",
     "Buzzer/Wireless Intercom",
     "Breakfast",
     "Family/Kid Friendly",
     "Suitable for Events",
     "Washer",
     "Dryer"]
```

You can then call it in the view or controller with `Room::AMENITIES_LIST`

Not sure what you are trying to do here:

```
def boolean_array_from_amenities_integer
    [].tap do |amenities_list|
        Room.amenities_list.length do |order|
            amenities_list << (self.amenities & 2 ** order > 0)
        end
    end
end
```